# Passing variable to controller (not a function)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I like to pass a variable to a controller trough the URL like this:

```
a href="<?php print base_url('/profile/' . $this->session->userdata('id')); ?>">Profiel</a>
```

/profile/ = controller  
$this->session->userdata('id') = variable

Now I want to give it to Profile but it only works when I do /profile/index/1 and I like to it like this: /profile/1

When actually to use a new controller?

This is my controller:

```
<?php

class Profile extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('login');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('profile_view');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The answer you're looking for involves ***routing***. Which framework is this? [Check their documentation.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: As far as I know , the default url structre is like: controller/action/otherParameters. This is why you need that `index/` part , it's the action of `viewing` the profile.

Comment: @OfirBaruch that's correct, but a routing script will do what OP wants. `index/` is not always necessary.

Comment: @BartTarantino Wow, that was a brain fart. I didn't see that.

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I found it, I need to add '$route['profile/(:num)'] = "profile/index/$1" to the routes.php file

Comment: If it works , consider answering your own question and accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it,

I just need to add this line to the routes.php file in the config folder:

```
$route['profile/(:num)'] = "profile/index/$1"
```

Then when profile/1 is entered it will automatically think it's profile/index/1

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use _remap function in your controller class. Read the related part in users guide. It is under "controllers" part.